# PyQt and py2exe: no sound from QSound after compiling to .exe

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, py2exe, pyqt5

I have problem with playing .wav sound with QSound.play() after compiling to exe (I'm using Python 3.4.3, PyQt 5.4.1 and py2exe 0.9.2.0).

**setup.py code:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
windows=[
    {
        "script": "main_app.py",
        "icon_resources": [(0, "favicon163248.ico")]
    }
],
data_files=[
    (
        'sounds', ['sounds\Siren.wav']

    )
],
options={"py2exe": {"includes": ["sip"], "dist_dir": "MyProject"}}
)
```

What have i tried:

1. Relative path

   ```
   sound = QSound("sounds/Siren.wav") 
   sound.play() #works when simply running, doesn't work when compiling to exe
   ```
2. Path to executable file (*main_app.exe*)

   ```
   sound = QSound(os.path.dirname(sys.executable) + "\sounds\Siren.wav")
   sound.play() #doesn't work when compiling to exe
   ```
3. Absolute path

   ```
   sound = QSound("C:\\path\\to\\project\\MyProject\\sounds\\Siren.wav") 
   sound.play() #works when simply running, doesn't work when compiling to exe
   ```
4. Resources

**resources_qrc.qrc code:**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="media">
    <file>Siren.wav</file>
    <file>favicon163248.ico</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

then converted to *resources.py* with pyrcc5

```
from resources import *
...
sound = QSound(':/media/Siren.wav')
sound.play() #works when simply running, doesn't work when compiling to exe
```

5. Copy form resource to hard drive on the fly

   ```
   QFile.copy(":/media/Siren.wav", "sounds/Siren.wav")
   sound = QSound("sounds/Siren.wav")
   sound.play() #still doesn't work after making exe!
   ```

After spending pretty much time on it, I gave up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can play `QSound` using cxfreeze. Maybe you can try that.

Comment: @Aaron i have the same problem with cxfreeze. could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

I use python 2.7 and cx_Freeze 4.3.1 and PyQt4

```
#-*- coding: utf-8-*-
__author__ = 'Aaron'
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"


includefiles= ['icons','Sound','imageformats']


includes = ['sip', 'PyQt4.QtCore']


setup(
        name = u"Your Programe",
        version = "1.0",
        description = u"XXXX",
        options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}},
        executables = [Executable("Your programe name.py" ,base = base, icon = "XXX.ico")])
```

Comment: can you give me example from main app code? i don't have problems with compiling.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too, with Python 3.4.3, PyQt 5.5.1, py2exe 0.9.2.2.
Problem is not in wrong file path.

If you call:

```
QAudioDeviceInfo.availableDevices(QAudio.AudioOutput)
```

from .exe, the returned list will be empty.

You should add foder: "\audio" from "site-packages\PyQt5\plugins" to the directory with your output .exe file, and sound will work.

Here is my setup.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys
import os, os.path
import zipfile
import shutil

def get_exe_name(f):
        dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(f))
        return os.path.split(dirname)[-1].lower()

def get_name(name):
        idx = name.find('.')
        if idx != -1:
                return name[:idx]
        return name

def build(__version__, __appname__, main_module = 'main.py', dest_base='main', icon='images\\main.ico'):
        #exec('from ' + get_name(main_module) + ' import __version__, __appname__')

        try:
                shutil.rmtree('dist')
        except:
                print ('Cann\'t remove "dist" directory: {0:s}'.format(str(sys.exc_info())))

        if len(sys.argv) == 1:
                sys.argv.append('py2exe')

        options = {'optimize': 2,
        #       'bundle_files': 0, # create singlefile exe 0
                'compressed': 1, # compress the library archive
                'excludes': ['pywin', 'pywin.debugger', 'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'pywin.dialogs.list', 'os2emxpath', 'optparse', 'macpath', 'tkinter'],
                'dll_excludes': ['w9xpopen.exe', 'mapi32.dll', 'mswsock.dll', 'powrprof.dll', 'MSVCP90.dll', 'HID.DLL'], # we don't need this
                'includes': ['sip', 'locale', 'calendar', 'logging', 'logging.handlers', 'PyQt5', 'PyQt5.QtCore', 'PyQt5.QtGui', 'PyQt5.QtMultimedia', 'PyQt5.QtNetwork', 'PyQt5.QtPrintSupport'],
                }

        #datafiles = [('platforms', ['C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\plugins\\platforms\\qwindows.dll']),]
        import PyQt5
        datafiles = [('platforms', [PyQt5.__path__[0] + '\\plugins\\platforms\\qwindows.dll']), ('audio', [PyQt5.__path__[0] + '\\plugins\\audio\\qtaudio_windows.dll']),]

        dirs = ['images', 'docs', 'ssl', 'sounds', 'p2ini', 'lib', 'config']
        for d in dirs:
                try:
                        for f in os.listdir(d):
                                f1 = d + '\\' + f
                                if os.path.isfile(f1): # skip directories
                                        datafiles.append((d, [f1]))
                except:
                        print ('Cann\'t find some files in directory "{0:s}": {1:s}'.format(d, str(sys.exc_info())))

        setup(version = __version__,
                description = __appname__,
                name = '{0:s} {1:s} application'.format(__appname__, __version__),
                options = {'py2exe': options},
                zipfile = None,
                data_files = datafiles,
                windows = [{'icon_resources':[(1,'images\\main.ico')], 'script':main_module, 'dest_base':dest_base}] if icon else [{'script':main_module, 'dest_base':dest_base}],
                scripts = [main_module],
                #console = [{'icon_resources':[(1,'images\\main.ico')], 'script':main_module, 'dest_base':dest_base}] if icon else [{'script':main_module, 'dest_base':dest_base}],
                )
```

And example code for call setup.py functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from setup import get_name, get_exe_name, build

MAIN_MODULE = 'main.py'

exec('from ' + get_name(MAIN_MODULE) + ' import __version__, __appname__')
build(__version__, __appname__, MAIN_MODULE, dest_base=get_exe_name(__file__))
```